# How to mock object initialized in method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I have two obj, obj1 and obj2, obj2 is attribute in obj1 as

```
public class MyObject1
{
    MyObject2 myObject2;

    public MyObject2 getMyObject2()
    {
        return myObject2;
    }

    public void setMyObject2(MyObject2 myObject2)
    {
        this.myObject2 = myObject2;
    }
}
```

In my service, it is initialized obj1, and get obj2 as

```
public void myTest2(){
        MyObject1 myObject1 = new MyObject1();
        MyObject2 myObject2 = myObject1.getMyObject2();
}
```

In my test, I mock the obj2, I want when(obj1.getObj2).thenReturn(obj2), this obj2 is the mock object, as

```
public void test3(){
        MyObject2 myObject2 = mock(MyObject2.class);
        MyObject1 myObject1 = spy(new MyObject1());
        doReturn(myObject2).when(myObject1).getMyObject2();
        myService.myTest2();
}
```

But now myObject2 I got from test is null, not the mocked myObject2. How can I get mocked myObject2 in my test?

Comment: why don't u use when(...).then(..) ? instead of thenReturn(..)

Comment: this code doesn't make much sense. myTest2() is basically a noop: it creates an object, gets a null field out of it, and doesn't do nor return anything. BTW, there is no way it uses the mocks you create in the test, since the method creates its own, not mocked MyObject1.

Comment: This is simplified scenario for the test, the basic problem, how can I get a mocked object2 when the object1 is initialized in the method

Comment: It might be helpful if you tell us more about the architecture of your program. To me, this looks like you are either trying to mock a model object (which should not be necessary), you are setting up services in a non-extendible way or you have no clear separation of model and control.

Comment: @Walter with Mockito, you can't. You'll need to refactor your code and use dependency injection. Or use PowerMockito which, AFAIK, allows mocking a class constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we cannot use mockito without Reflection to mock a local variable, the problem is dead end for now

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Mockito then you can use
**Mockito.any()** method, you can pass the classtype as an argument.